# Probability of throwing missiles "all at once" and "one by one"

Tags: probability

5 missiles can be thrown at a target with probability of hitting the target for each missile = 0.3 .It is done in two ways :

1. **One by one** assuming that no more missiles are thrown if the target is hit so there is no need of including the probability of not hitting the targets of other missiles in the calculation . So the binomial distribution method won't work.

Since no more missiles are thrown if the target is hit the binomial distribution method won't work.

Then the probability of hitting the target **"only"** once can be calculated as follows :

(Probability of first missile **hitting** the target) + (Probability of first missile **missing** the target) * (Probability of second missile **hitting** the target) + (Probability of first missile **missing** the target) * (Probability of second missile **missing** the target) * (Probability of third missile **hitting** the target).........and so on till the 5th missile .

=> 0.3 + (1-0.3)*0.3 + (1-0.3)*(1-0.3)*0.3 +........

=> 0.3 + 0.7*0.3 + 0.7*0.7*0.3 +........

Taking 0.3 common in the above expression,
0.3*[1 + 0.7 + (0.7)^2 + (0.7)^3 ......]

The expression in the square brackets can be solved by the geometric sum formula as,

=> 0.3*[1*(1- 0.7^5)]/0.3

= 1-0.7^5 = 0.83193

2. **All at once** all 5 of them

Then the probability of hitting the target **"at least"** once can be calculated  as:

The probability of hitting the target at least once = 1-(Probability of all the missiles missing the target)

= 1 - (Probability of one missile missing the target)^5

= 1 - (1-0.3)^5 = 1 - (0.7)^5 = 0.83193

Which is same as the first case .

Its really interesting that the probability of hitting target **only once** if we throw missiles one by one is same as hitting it **at least once** if we throw them all at once .

My question is why is this happening ? What is the reason behind it ? Is it just a coincidence ? (I know the question doesn't sound much mathematical and I am sorry if this violates the posting policy ; if it does , then I will sincerely take it down) .

Comment: Assuming that the missiles don't interfere then there is no surprise here?

Comment: Is that a question ? And yes the missiles don't interfere . But can you elaborate please . I mean why is it not a surprise .

Comment: In your first calculation, you added the probability of the first missing being the *first* one to hit the target, plus the probability of the second missile being the *first* one to hit the target, and so on. You forgot to take into account that the remaining missiles must *miss* the target for there to be only one hit. In other words, your first calculation finds the probability that at least one missile hits the target by considering the various possibilities for the missile that hits first.

Comment: If they don't interfere and you throw all of them, then the probability of hitting the target exactly once is the same regardless of when you throw them.

Comment: But I have assumed that I am throwing missiles one by one not all at once . That is we don't need to multiply the probability of the remaining missiles because there would no remaining missiles if one already has hit the target .

Comment: However, if you throw and stop when you hit, then the probabilities will be different.

Comment: If you do stop when you hit the target, then this will be the same probability as throwing them all and getting **at least** one hit.

Comment: Your first calculation is wrong. The chance that in five tries you hit exactly once in independent trials is $\binom{5}{1}p^1(1-p)^4 = 0.36015$.

Comment: Write out sequences of H (hit) and M (miss) to see the differences...

Comment: I think I should have mentioned it in the question that in the first case I am assuming that no more missiles are thrown if the target is hit so there is no need of including the probability of not hitting the targets of other missiles in the calculation . So the binomial distribution method won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the two figures will always be equal is very simple.

**One by one**

We have "won" as soon as a hit is made, and stop. $(H =\; hit,\;\; M = \;miss)$
Suppose we hit on the third trial:

$M-M-H-?-?$

Trials $4$ and $5$ won't take place, **but what happens if they took place doesn't matter**,
we have won anyway, so we can as well include all possibilities after the third trial, viz:

$M-M-H||-H-H$
$M-M-H||-H-M$
$M-M-H||-M-H$
$M-M-H||-M-M$

Including all possibilities after the third means we are multiplying $\;\Bbb P(M-M-H)$ by $1$,
thus $\;\;\Bbb P$(stopping after the first hit) =  $\Bbb P$(getting at least $1$ hit)

Answer (score 1):

The first scenario (throwing missiles until you either stop or hit 5 throws) can be modeled as following a geometric distribution, where we are only calculating up to $n=5$:

$$P(\text{Success})= 0.3\sum_{k=1}^5 0.7^{k-1} = 0.83193$$

For throwing all 5 at once, you are performing a binomial experiment:

Let $X$ be the number of missiles that hit the target. We succeed as long as they don't all miss.

$$P(X>0)=1-P(X=0)=1-0.7^5 = 0.83193$$

Same probabilities, as you calculated. So your question is why probabilities calculated for a stopped sequence is the same as for a simultaneous group.

At a non-technical level, we can imagine that you continue to throw missiles after your first hit and then aggregate all sequences that are successful. This will reproduce the same set of outcomes as the binomial case where you throw them all at once. Now, note that all possible outcomes after the first hit are counted as part of the probability of the first hit (i.e., the probability that you hit it on your first throw are higher than hitting it on your second, because it counts more of these events after the first hit).

This really just means that the probability of hitting on your second throw has the same probability as the sum of all binomial trials whose first hit is at the second "position" (assuming you numbered your missiles in increasing order).